# Getting refresh token from Microsoft Identity Platform

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, refresh-token

I have an Azure web app where I want users to sign into Microsoft (Azure AD). I need to get hold of the refresh token. I have already looked at examples which use libraries that refresh the token silently in the background, but for my design I need to get hold of the refresh token itself.

Is this possible to achieve with a high level authentication library (OpenID Connect?), and if so, how?
For the manual approach, it is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user
Is there any example code or tutorial for this in ASP.NET or .NET Core?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly i would suggest using [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview) which Maintains a token cache and refreshes tokens for you when they are close to expire. You don't need to handle token expiration on your own.

If you want to hold the refresh token , you can set the `SaveTokens` property to true when registering the OIDC middleware so that tokens will be saved into cookie . I assume you are using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` library :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
    options.SaveTokens = true;


});
```

Then you can access the tokens in controller like :

```
var refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token");
var idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
```

**Update:**

That is because you don't get refresh token correctly . For testing , you can use code flow and add `offline_access` scope of OIDC :

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.ClientSecret = "xxxxxx";
    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;

});
```

Replace `ClientSecret` with the one you config in Azure portal .

Comment: I tried it in a new MVC Web Application (.NET Framework, ASP.NET Core 2.2) with authentication added and which uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI. I had to reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication too to use GetTokenAsync. I put the code in HomeController and hopefully it was implemented correctly. Only "id_token" returned a value, while "refresh_token" was null. I tried getting "access_token" too, it was null as well.

Comment: I'm getting Correlation error - unknown location, or still can't get tokens. I will probably read up more on MSAL though. Btw. the project default was services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>..., but changed it as you described.

Comment: I didn't set the `CookiePolicyOptions` .

Comment: see also https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-openid-connect-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Ok. I'll have a look. Thanks for suggestions! Yeah, the CookiePolicyOptions was just the default when creating a project.