# Get refresh token additionally to access token with Microsoft.Identity.Client

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I use several properties like tenant id, client id, client secret, redirect uri and an authorization code generated for a user. I need to get the access and refresh token, but with the API that don't return anything like a refresh token. I need a refresh token additionnally to the access token and the expire in time.
I use this following code:

```
ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions options = new ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions();
        options.ClientId = clientId;
        options.TenantId = tenantId;
        options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
        options.RedirectUri = redirectUri;

        ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder builder = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.
            CreateWithApplicationOptions(options);
        IConfidentialClientApplication app = builder.Build();
        AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeParameterBuilder acquireTokenBuilder = 
            app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(ServiceConstants.ALL_SCOPE_AUTHORIZATIONS.Split(' '), authorizationCode);
        AuthenticationResult result = await acquireTokenBuilder.ExecuteAsync();
        string accessToken = result.AccessToken;
        // NO string refreshToken = result.RefreshToken
```

Its very strange because in several example, I see the RefreshToken available in AuthenticationResult, but not in mine. Do you know why ? And how I can get the refresh token plz ?

Because after that I will need to refresh the access token when will expire and I only have the access token, tenant id, client id, secret (or certificate) and redirect uri. BTW How to regenerate it after access token expiration ?

thank a lot and best regards

Adrien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check what is passed as **ServiceConstants.ALL_SCOPE_AUTHORIZATIONS** in both `/authorize` and `/token` requests. The list of scopes should contain `offline_access` scope as it tells Azure that your application will need a refresh token for extended access to resources.

The refresh token will have a longer lifetime than the access token, therefore whenever your access token expires you will be able to call the `/token` endpoint again providing the previously received refresh token and using the parameter `grant_type=refresh_token`.

Comment: I use the Microsoft.Identity.Client C# SDK and in the AuthenticationResult the token object only have an access token and not a refresh, consequently I can't get the refresh. consequently I don't use the grant_type=refresh token I only use AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode() and my all scope are  --> user.read calendars.readwrite calendars.readwrite.shared offline_access openid place.read.all

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an **Azure AD Application** and added API permissions:

[image]

> **Note** that: To get refresh token make sure to grant **`offline_access`** API permission in your Azure AD Application and include it in the **scope** while generating access token.

**I generated access and refresh token using below parameters in Postman:**

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:RedirectUri
code:code
```

[image]

To get this in your code you can include the below line:

```cs
refreshToken = result.RefreshToken
```

***To refresh the access token, I used the parameters like below:***

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientId
grant_type:refresh_token
refresh_token:refreshtoken
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

**Sample Code:**

```cs
AzureADApp.AcquireTokenByRefreshToken(RefreshToken, scope) .ExecuteAsync();
var refreshedAccessToken = result.AccessToken;
```

Comment: @Rukimini no sorry I don't use postman, I use the Microsoft.Identity.Client C# SDK and in the AuthenticationResult the token object only have an access token and not a refresh, consequently I can't get the refresh

Comment: Did you include offline_access scope in your code while generating access token?

Comment: Could you confirm whether you are using MSAL? if yes then refer [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62560052/azure-ad-login-using-c-acquiring-refresh-token-and-access-token).

Comment: yes I use MSAL, but I can't use app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()) because I need the refresh token for forwarding to the top of the application layer and app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()) can be only use by retrieving the accounts, and only with access token I can't do that, and I don't keep the app reference consequently the initialized cash. Because we don't want to keep all the logged user in server cache for memory reason

Comment: MSAL maintains a token cache and caches a token after it has been acquired. It's also capable of refreshing a token when it's getting close to expiration (as the token cache also contains a refresh token).

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004048/getting-refresh-token-from-microsoft-identity-platform